# two different strings from column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two numbers in the column that i want to divide in two different columns, for example i have a Quantity column that contains texts like :

```
Quantity change: old=100, new=0
Quantity change: old=2152, new=2139
```

and i want to have a query that will have two columns, one that is showing "Old quantity" and the other one will show "New Quantity"

Comment: Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: ok. So what's your question? I assume you want us to help you to achieve this? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck, specifically? This isn't a free write-my-code service but we will help you, if you tell us where you're up to.

Comment: on what basis you want to create the new column, any specific logic for seperating two columns

Comment: Use `LOCATE(col, 'old=')` to get the position of the first value, and `LOCATE(col, 'new=')` to get the position of the second value.

Comment: You can then use these along with `SUBSTR()` to extract the numbers after them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (substring(Quantity,
CHARINDEX('w=', Quantity)+2,(len(Quantity)-CHARINDEX('w=', Quantity)))) AS OldQuantity,
( substring(Quantity,
CHARINDEX('old=', Quantity)+4,(CHARINDEX(',', Quantity)-(CHARINDEX('old=', Quantity)+4)))) AS NewQuantity
from tablename
;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`.  Assuming the values are numbers:

```
select substring_index(quantity, 'old=', -1) + 0 as old_value,
       substring_index(quantity, 'new=', -1) + 0 as new_value
```

This uses implicit conversion to convert the values to numbers.  Only leading digits are converted, so this pulls out the number after the `=`.